# .htaccess rewrite https to www, but not when IP-address is used

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I have got a Nextcloud installed on my Raspberry Pi. Https is set up and the rewrite engine is on. Rewrite is also working so far.
Now I have got the following problem:
If I am invoking my cloud inside the LAN-network I have to use the internal IP-address (192.168.1.20) and using the Internet to reach the cloud over the browser I set up an URL.

For always having a proper URL I want to use a .htaccess-file (and later a IfModule rewrite) to rewrite the URL.
The following cases should be rewritten:

```
http://example.com/xyz -> https://www.example.com/xyz
http://www.example.com/xyz -> https://www.example.com/xyz
http://192.168.1.20/xyz -> https://192.168.1.20/xyz
```

I am not very familiar with the syntax and so I tried the following without success:

```
RewriteEngine on

# for URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^192.168.1.20
RewriteRule ^https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for IP
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^192.168.1.20
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^https://192.168.1.20%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I would be glad if someone could help me...

EDIT:
My "000-default.conf" definitions are:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName 192.168.1.20
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  </IfModule>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cloud.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cloud.key
</VirtualHost>
```

And my "default-ssl.conf" definitions:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ServerName=www.example.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/cloud.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/cloud.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: When Apache receives a request, it looks at the domain asked for to select which VirtualHost to respond with.  When you ask with the IP, it will take the first it finds, reading the file top to bottom.  Add your VirtualHost definitions in here, otherwise it's hard to provide a full answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did an edit in my original post with the definitions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile i solved the problem myself!

There were some syntax mistakes and some other problems.
The following code inside a ".htaccess"-file at the root directory works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on

# for URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^192\.168\.1\.20
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for IP
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^192\.168\.1\.20
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://192.168.1.20%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The only remaining problem is that `https://example.com` is NOT corrected to `https://www.example.com`, but in my case this is not important...